# Cannot add CSS style to an element at runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have following code to change the style of an element, once I enter the page the **alert window will be shown** with "myP" message; whoever, the **style wont get added** to the element. Also, let me know if you have jQuery based solution for it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         alert("myP");
         document.getElementById("myP").style.fontWeight = "bold";
    </script>

    ...
    <a id="myP" href="www.example.com">Example</a>
    ...

    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the document is not loaded at the time your JS code is being executed.

Wrap the javascript code to *window.onload* function like bellow

```
 window.onload = function(){
     alert("myP");
     document.getElementById("myP").style.fontWeight = "bold";
 }
```

**Note:-** Make a habit of looking at console.

Answer (score 2):

As requested by OP jQuery-based solution for waiting for the DOM to load would be

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("myP");
    $("#myP").css("font-weight", "bold")
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but Mritunjay posted his answer before you so I need to accept his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your script will run before the element is loaded. You need to wrap it in a function and call it when the document loads.

Answer (score 1):

your element would not be found by the script as it would not have been loaded when you call `getElementById` on it, so move your script code before closing body tag, as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>      

    ...
    <a id="myP" href="www.example.com">Example</a>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript">
         alert("myP");
         document.getElementById("myP").style.fontWeight = "bold";
    </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Demo :: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hevhfd9L/)